# Check permissions on xiaomi device with a version below api 23

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-5.1.1-lollipop

As you know, Xiaomi devices have their own system of permissions. I'm testing my application on the device xiaomi redmi 3, api 22, android 5.1.1. I want to check if there is permission to access the camera and audio. But the standard way does not work:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "android.permission.CAMERA");
```

returns 0, although this is not true.

I found another way, but it also does not work correctly:

```
boolean b = hasSelfPermissionForXiaomi(getActivity(),"android.permission.CAMERA");

    private boolean hasSelfPermissionForXiaomi(Context context,String permission){
    String permissionTop = AppOpsManagerCompat.permissionToOp(permission);
    if(permissionTop == null){
        // not dangerous
        return true;
    }
    int noteOp = AppOpsManagerCompat.noteOp(context,permissionTop, Process.myUid(),context.getPackageName());
    return noteOp == AppOpsManagerCompat.MODE_ALLOWED && checkSelfPermission(context,permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

b = true,  although this is not true.

Guys, did any of you understand how to check permissions on xiaomi devices ???

Comment: You don't need to check permissions for api level < 23. In xiaomi phone of api level less than 23, the system asks for permission itself before it is used.

Comment: @NabinBhandari You are a little wrong. The system prompts for permission immediately before using the camera. In my application, the camera will be needed at a random time and I need to do so so that the permission is provided in advance.

Comment: I meant the same, what happens when the user denies the permission?

Comment: @NabinBhandari Accordingly, if the user has not granted permission to use the camera, the camera will not work. Can I check the permission before using the camera?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Any news here? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @TomerPetel, yes, see my comment on github: https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher/issues/386#issuecomment-343722196